# How to know current frame with selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a code like this.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
f = driver.find_element :xpath, "html/frameset//frame[@name='header']"
driver.switch_to.frame f
```

After switching frame, is there a way to access attributes of current frame?
In other words, how can I get value of attribute `name` of `frame` tag after switching?

I want to be sure I'm handling correct frame before to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access the attributes of the current `iframe` you are in.

I would recommend testing for the existence of an element that is in the `iframe`.

Answer (score 10):

This was officially requested and rejected in 2012, here:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4305

The answerer asserts that this was rejected because you can use this (Java) code to accomplish the same thing:

```
WebElement el = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.frameElement");
```

Personally, this strikes me as an asinine answer - the entire `JavascriptExecutor` portion of Selenium just seems like an ugly hack to allow end users to do things that the developers didn't anticipate would need to be done. Except the developers were clearly told this needed to be done, and they ignored it.

Anyways, I'm using Python which allows additional methods to be dynamically added to existing classes (even those which you don't have access to) so I just used the following to give WebDriver a `currentFrame` method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

def currentFrame(self):
    return str(self.execute_script("""
        var frame = window.frameElement;
        if (!frame) {
            return 'root of window named ' + document.title;
        }
        var ret   = '<' + frame.tagName;
        if (frame.name) {
            ret += ' name=' + frame.name;
        }
        if (frame.id) {
            ret += ' id=' + frame.id;
        }
        return ret + '>';
        """))

WebDriver.currentFrame = currentFrame
```

(I'm just using this for debug/logging purposes - I don't actually need the WebElement so I'm just returning a string. I don't know Ruby, but I'm sure you can adopt either my Python code or the Java code I copied from the other website to make it work in Ruby.)

Comment: Couldn't this have been done as a subclass of `WebDriver` instead? I haven't used Selenium in forever so I don't know why I chose to add methods to an existing class 7 years ago...